# how to select from this table and add average value and then sort

Tags: mysql, select, average

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to select, average and sort in mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123110/how-to-select-average-and-sort-in-mysql-table)

i have a table in mySql like in this picture

[image]

and i want to write a query which result will group by LESSON column, and add new row which is average value of LESSON column and sum CNT column values....
[image]

i use this query but it gives result like in picture 3 and i cant sort by PERC in this case

```
select no, STUD_ID,CLASS,LESSON, AVG(PERC) as PERC,SUM(CNT) as CNT from t_lesson where LESSON='CHEM' group by CLASS
union all
select no,STUD_ID,CLASS,'AVERAGE' as LESSON, AVG(PERC) as PERC, SUM(CNT) as CNT from t_lesson where LESSON='CHEM' group by LESSON
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from <your query> order by PERC
```

wich :

```
select * from (

select no, STUD_ID,CLASS,LESSON, AVG(PERC) as PERC,SUM(CNT) as CNT from t_lesson where LESSON='CHEM' group by CLASS
union all
select no,STUD_ID,CLASS,'AVERAGE' as LESSON, AVG(PERC) as PERC, SUM(CNT) as CNT from t_lesson where LESSON='CHEM' group by LESSON

) as sub order by PERC DESC
```